# Proof x \in L \leftrightarrow det(...) = 0.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I just need some help with the following proof:

Let $v = (v_1,v_2) $and $ w=(w_1,w_2)$ be two points in $K^2 , v \not= w$  and $L \subseteq K^2 $ a line through these two points.
Show that

$(x1,x2)\in L \leftrightarrow det\begin{pmatrix} 1 & v_1 & v_2 \\ 1 & w_1 & w_2 \\ 1 & x_1 & x_2 \end{pmatrix}=0$.

A) If there exists such a line L this means the same as
$ L = \{(x_1,x_2) \in K^2 : \exists \lambda \in K : x_i = v_i + \lambda (w_i - v_i)\}$.

B) Calculating the det gives me:

$ det\begin{pmatrix} 1 & v_1 & v_2 \\ 1 & w_1 & w_2 \\ 1 & x_1 & x_2 \end{pmatrix}= det \begin{pmatrix} (w_1-v_1) & (w_2-v_2) \\ (x_1-v_1) & (x_2 -v_2) \end{pmatrix}$.

If the det is zero this means:

$(w_1-v_1)(x_2-v_2) - (w_2-v_2)(x_1-v_1)=0$
=>

$(x_1-v_1) = (w_1-v_1) \cdot \frac{x_2-v_2}{w_2-v_2}$

=>

$x_1 = v_1 + (w_1-v_1)\cdot \lambda$.

However, can I simply say $\frac{x_2-v_2}{w_2-v_2} = \lambda$ ?!

Answer (score 1):

As you have already mentioned: $x\in L \Leftrightarrow x_i = v_i + \lambda (w_i-v_i) = (1-\lambda) v_i + \lambda w_i$ for some $\lambda \in K$.

Now, for such a $\lambda$ you can see that $(1-\lambda)\pmatrix{1 & v_1 & v_2} + \lambda \pmatrix{1 & w_1 & w_2} = \pmatrix{ 1 & x_1 & x_2}$. Thus the row vectors of you matrix are linear dependent, thus the rank of your matrix is $2$ and thus the determiant is $0$. Conversely if the determinant is $0$ the vectors are linear dependent, and because $v \neq w$ you can find a lambda so that $x=v+(1-\lambda) w$.

Comment: Hi Stefan! Thank you very much for your Answer. Just one question, since I don't see it right now: Why are the row vectors linear dependent?

Comment: Because you can combine the first and second row to get the third row (multiply the first by $(1-\lambda)$ and the second by $\lambda$ and add them up. For the other direction: If $\det$ is $0$ then it can easily be shown that the row vectors have to be linear dependent.

Comment: Okay, I understand. So if det(...)=0 this means there exists a row filled with zeros -> linear dependent. Is this enough for showing this?